# racket: O(1) array indexing like python's numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, scheme, racket

I'm using arrays of picture (2-D array) and model (3-D array) data in python for an application where I'm modeling the human body in 3 dimensions.  I would like to rewrite the code in Lisp, specifically Racket,

but I'm wondering how succinct expressions in numpy indexing, ie. `arr[2][3]` will be expressed in Lisp.  I could write a recursive function that expands to `(car (car ... (car list))))` or `(cdr (cdr ... (cdr list))))`, but this seems inefficient.  Is there a way to get `O(1)` access time in a Lisp list, vector, or array?

ie.

```
arr[1,2] = 1
```

should be done in racket how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of using [Arrays](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/array.html) instead of (linked) lists is that you can random-access index them in constant time. But Racket Arrays provide a lot more than that, including Python-ish slicing, and NumPy-ish array-wide operations. The syntax isn't quite as concise or (at least in my opinion) as nice as in Python, but the ideas are the same.

You really need to read the whole chapter to understand the best way to write your code, or you're going to end up doing the same kind of thing as if you wrote Python code that used NumPy but then looped over `range(len(arr))` all the time.

But to answer your direct question, the Python/NumPy expression:

```
arr[2, 3]
```

… is written in Racket as:

```
(array-ref arr #(2, 3))
```

The Python expression:

```
arr[2][3]
```

… is written as two nested `array-ref` calls. But then if `arr` is an actual 2D array (e.g., from NumPy), you shouldn't have been writing it as two indexing expressions in Python any more than you should in Racket, so the fact that it's more verbose isn't really a bad thing.

Either way, it has the same constant-time lookup.

Comment: @frank Ha, didn't even notice that. IIRC, somewhere else the docs talk about how the difference between typed and untyped arrays (or arrays in untyped Racket, which are of course always untyped) is comparable to the difference between NumPy arrays and lists-of-lists in Python.

Comment: It also says "For now, if you need speed, use the typed/racket language."  Does this apply to many operations, or just ones in the "array" library?

Comment: @frank I'm not that current on Racket, but (based on an educated guess plus faulty memories of out-of-date information…) _many_ things are optimized pretty nicely in untyped racket, but _some_ things are not, and some of those are pretty hard, so that may well be true for a long time. (And arrays are probably one of the harder ones—there's a reason NumPy is one of the few places in Python where you're expected to declare value types in advance…)

Comment: @frank there are specific elements of the Array library that can perform very badly when not using Typed Racket. This would not likely be the case for the more basic 'vector', which provides constant-time access to a linear array, and should perform just fine in standard Racket. Since vectors are not designed as multi-dimensional arrays, you'd have to do row/column arithmetic as e.g. in C.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT: see accepted answer

For vanilla lists, you can do

```
(list-tail lst pos)
```

see also: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html

Comment: OP asked about constant-time array reference--list-tail is not helpful in this regard.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know.  Makes sense, however

Comment: You can delete your own answer. No shame in it at all.